# Video of annotations

Tags: osx, annotation

I'm a college English teacher and I want to make instructional videos for my students. I need to find software that will allow me to do make a video of the process of doing a freehand markup of text documents, such as PDFs of poems and short stories, while I provide an audio commentary. Since I am already familiar with iMovie, I would like to continue using that platform.

Comment: You will rather need software for [screen-recording](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-recording) to accomplish that task (please check the link to see related questions; [here are those having answers](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=[screen-recording]+answers%3A1).